# Why is ProviderSignInUtils.getConnection deprecated

Tags: spring-security, spring-social

I am trying Spring Social Signing in, using `SocialAuthenticationFilter`, which the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#section_signin) recommends over `ProviderSignInController`.

In the signup handler method, I am supposed to get the user profile data using

```
Connection<?> connection = ProviderSignInUtils.getConnection(request);
```

as the [documentation says here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#section_signUpForm).

But I found that the [`getConnection`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/social/connect/web/ProviderSignInUtils.html#getConnection(org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes)) static method is deprecated, and it is suggested to use the instance method `getConnectionFromSession` instead. When I tried to inject a `ProviderSignInUtils` for using the instance method, I saw that there was no such bean in the application context.

So, liked to know how to go about this, and why is `getConnection` deprecated.

Thanks,
Sanjay

Comment: did you find anything on this?  care to share or provide an answer?

Comment: added my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source of [ProviderSignInUtils](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/blob/master/spring-social-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/connect/web/ProviderSignInUtils.java), I found that it uses a `SessionStrategy` which you might want to configure when instantiating the `ProviderSignInUtils` bean. So, I guess Spring team is deprecating the static methods.

I wanted to go with the default, and so just instantiated it with the default constructor.